# WMI command line event log acess

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, wmi

Can someone explain me how to get access to arbitrary system logs in `eventlog` service files?

---

Now I'm poking around WMI(wmic.exe) and trying to execute following commands:

For system services like applications this approach works ok:

> WMIC NTEVENT WHERE "LogFile='application'"

And the other log file with following syntax fails.

> WMIC NTEVENT WHERE "LogFile='Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2/Operational'"

leads to:

```
No Instance(s) Available.
```

Can somebody share working command to do the job or any kind of tutorial about that stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use powershell for these kind of things; there are plenty of cmdlets that help extract this data in a useful way, and there are myriad scripts online that can get you whatever you might need.

**Note**:  I've tested these on Windows 8 and Server 2012, and they work fine.  You didn't specify an OS.  You will also need to run Powershell as an administrator.

The simplest method is to look in **Event Viewer** (eventvwr.exe), and right-click -> **Properties** on the log you wish to parse.  Find the **Log Path**, and you can query the log as simply as this:

```
get-winevent -path <full_path_to_logfile.evtx>
```

As an example, you can try this one, which should exist on your Windows machine:

```
get-winevent -path C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
```

Get-winevent is a built-in cmdlet, so you should have it available.  You can use regular powershell logic to strip out only the parts you like, or pipe them to a file, or lots of other fun stuff.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try it as soon as I can. I apologize that because of lack of reputation can not upvote your answer.

Comment: No worries.  I'm relatively new myself :)  Definitely come back with improvements you add though, so others can be helped if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, powershell approach works fine. Maybe you can advice me also how to redirect all output to the file(csv/txt/any) and specify multiple log files?

Comment: @user3441253 Shouldn't be too complicated.  You'd likely want to use Out-File to write the results to a file, and then you can just use basic Powershell scripting to assign filenames based on a variable like date, or date and time, etc.  A little Google-ing will go a long way, and you'll learn for the future as well!